White screen gray image
When I try to render image, I get a white background and solid gray silhouette of my image. Not sure if I made a mistake during shading. I will attach my Layout, Shading, and Rendering screens here.



Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

What you see in the lower image is not the camera view. The render will be made with the view from the camera.

Every issue on this site is Blender issue. It's redundant to mention that in the title. You should give your questions a descriptive title that would tell people what the question is. "White screen gray image" is still a very vague title that does not communicate much meaningful information. Something like "Rendered Image Shows White Background and Gray Silhouette" would be more informative.

You have a single metallic object in your scene. It is reflective and therefore its look depends on the environment it is in. If you set your world background to single color, that's how it would look.

If you place the object into some environment where there is something for it to reflect, it would look different. One way to do that would be to use HDRI environment map:

If you want the object to have reflections, but the HDR image not visible in the background, you can use Light Path node's Is Camera Ray output to mix the HDRI with some single color:

